# My sugar daddy wants me to pay a $50 conversion fee on paypal

Tags: money-transfer, sugar-daddy

This is the first time i’ve properly been involved with a sugar daddy and he wants me to pay $50 for the USD to AUD conversion rate on pay pal. is this a scam and should i just block him? i don’t want to get conned into anything

Comment: You're not properly involved, when he wants your money

Comment: That's not what *Sugar Daddy* means...

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this is a scam. Browse other questions [tagged sugar-daddy](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sugar-daddy) on this site for many many more in a similar vein. Block him and move on.

You can also read the [community wiki entry about it](https://money.stackexchange.com/tags/sugar-daddy/info):

> The typical premise of a "sugar" relationship is that a sugar-daddy or
> sugar-momma pays a sugar-baby in exchange for companionship,
> traditionally sexual in nature. A sugar relationship is often used as
> a setup for more ordinary fraud by enticing the sugar-baby as the
> victim.

Comment: And by “move on,” we mean stop looking for an online sugar daddy. It’s all a scam.

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica I would really be curious what percentage of contacts with "Sugar daddies" are fraud or attempted fraud, what percentage are trying to exploit the "sugar baby" in some way, and what percentage are an honest exchange of money for whatever favours.

Comment: I wonder whether we should also warn the sugar babies that there are worse outcomes than financial/legal ruin; they could end up physically harmed or dead, like [Mackenzie Lueck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_of_Mackenzie_Lueck).

Answer (score 7):

The idea of a "sugar daddy" or "sugar mommy" is that they give you money usually for sexual favours. Nothing particularly wrong with this in my view (others may disagree).

Never, ever in a million years will a real "sugar daddy" ask you to pay any money. So yes, this is a scam. And you haven't met any "sugar daddy" yet. Just because I'm curious, when you're successful eventually, could you post how many scammers you had to go through before you found a real one?

PS. If I wanted to pay you say US$1000 that need to be converted to AU$, and I didn't want to pay any exchange fees, I would just send you US$1000, PayPal or whoever else would take their fee out, and you would get US$950 converted to AU$. It wouldn't make any sense at all to send you $1050 and then you send $50 back.