# SD wants me to purchase Prepaid card for international fees through paypal. Is this a scam?

Tags: scams, international-transfer, paypal, sugar-daddy

A SD contacted me in regards to me becoming his SB. He wants to send a monthly allowance through Paypal but he is in Germany so Paypal is requiring a 100$ international transfer fee. He is not asking for any of my personal information except for my paypal link. Am I being scammed?

Comment: It's a scam. Real SDs ('sugar daddies') send _you_ money (for doing things, I expect you can guess what they are). Think about it. If he likes you so much, why doesn't _he_ pay the transfer fee?

Comment: Sugar Daddies are **not** what you think they are.

Answer (score 4):

Yes its a scam. I'll post a long answer because a LOT of women seem to get caught up in these things.

1. It's a sugar relationship - Did you send him any nude pictures or spend time with him? If no, then what is he paying for? If there's no exchange of money for goods or services - then it's a scam. If you are having sex with your sugar daddy or sending him nudes then he can pay you for that in full and you all do what you're gonna do.
2. PayPal doesn't require transfer fees - they just take it out of whatever is being sent. See this question from yesterday: [My sugar daddy wants me to pay a $50 conversion fee on paypal](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/136759/my-sugar-daddy-wants-me-to-pay-a-50-conversion-fee-on-paypal?noredirect=1&lq=1)

You can read more by seeing other [sugar-daddy] questions at https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sugar-daddy . Every single one of these scams asks the sugar-baby to send money or "refund" an "overpayment" or a "fee". If your sugar daddy is too damn poor to cover a small surcharge then he certainly cannot afford to pay your allowance either.

Comment: @Alesha West - read this "If your sugar daddy is too damn poor to cover a small surcharge then he certainly cannot afford to pay your allowance either."